# NavigationLink is passing a incorrect record in array to another view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

```swift
                    ForEach(bookData){ bookDetail in
                        Button(action: {
                            //Page number update
                        }) {
                            BookView(book: bookDetail)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .background(
                            NavigationLink(destination: EditBook(book: bookDetail), isActive: $showEdit){
                               EmptyView()
                           }
                        )
                        .contextMenu{
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showEdit = true
                            }) {
                                Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                //Delete action
                            }) {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The navigationLink that goes to EditBook is sending the wrong view. In my array, that is running off a json file, when I try to send the second record, it seems to pass the first one because the EditBook view is showing data from the first record. Also more what's more peculiar is the fact the first record passes the third record's data (there are only 3 records).

Have no idea what's happening, I though it might be because the id's of each record start from 1 but I changed it to zero and it didn't work.

ps. I have no idea what's with the code blocks formatting

Comment: Why are you using a NavigationLink for the background of a button? NavigationLink itself is a Button so you're effectively nesting two buttons. Also, the reason it's showing the last item is because you're using it inside a loop, and the closures doesn't capture the individual state, but rather the final state of the loop. You should move all the code inside the ForEach block into it's own view to keep the state there.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I originally put the nav link under the context menu but it didn't work because it has to be directly under navigation view. I actually was wondering why it wasn't working and my last question on this site was about that. This implementation honestly negates the need for a context menu so is there a better way for me to do it?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen yes I just realised what is happening, the button now uses the nav link but I want only the context menu to do so, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. with `ForEach` you should do that, because you activate all links in container by one state, instead you have to make them unique for each row/cell, using different link constructor, like below (there might be also needed to conform your `bookDetail` type, I assumed it is `Book`, to Hashable)

```
@State private var selectedBook: Book? = nil

...

    ForEach(bookData){ bookDetail in
        Button(action: {
            //Page number update
        }) {
            BookView(book: bookDetail)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.primary)
        .background(
            NavigationLink(destination: EditBook(book: bookDetail), tag: bookDetail, selection: $selectedBook) {
               EmptyView()
           }
        )
        .contextMenu{
            Button(action: {
                self.selectedBook = bookDetail
            }) {
                Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
            }
            Button(action: {
                //Delete action
            }) {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense, thank you! One question though, you see the background modifier is under a button and I wanted to save the tap gesture for another view, how can I put this navigation link under the context menu only.